# Mapbox line-pattern distorts the image

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

With mapbox gl js, I am applying line-pattern (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-line-line-pattern ) property to a Line
but the result is distorted

The image width is a factor of two (32 or 64px) and I am using a fixed width for the line (I am not trying to scale it with the zoom - which is much worse btw)

```
paint: {
         'line-pattern':fillPatternName,
         'line-width': 32,
       },
```

Example:

[Here is the pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0TCY.png)

[And this is the actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwp3l.png)

As you can see it will create an angle in the pattern and also the repeat is inconsistent as it will repeat the pattern without finishing the previous pattern draw.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some sort of trick (because from the documentation there is no setting for line-pattern from what I saw) to avoid this?

Comment: This is happening only if I have a multipoint line, for a simple line from A to B it looks ok